# Python string formatting with a customer defined output length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched [a few solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65603083/python-string-formatting-with-variable-length), but it may not apply to our case. Here is a minimal code to illustrate what I was trying to do. How can we make the commented code works? We can use python 3.8+ solutions.

```
teams_list = ["Man Utd", "Man City", "T Hotspur"]
data = list([[1, 2, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0],
                 [2, 4, 2]])


row_format ="{:>10}" * (len(teams_list) + 1) #this code works

# these codes do not work
#customer_defined_len = 10
#row_format ="{:>customer_defined_len}" * (len(teams_list) + 1)

print(row_format.format("", *teams_list))
for team, row in zip(teams_list, data):
    print(row_format.format(team, *row))
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be f-strings:

```py
customer_defined_len = 10
row_format = f"{{:>{customer_defined_len}}}" * (len(teams_list) + 1)
print(row_format.format("", *teams_list))
for team, row in zip(teams_list, data):
    print(row_format.format(team, *row))
```

Note that `row_format` is a f-string that creates the format-string template, so to avoid interpreting `{}` within the f-string itself, we duplicate it (ie: `{{ ...}}`)

Comment: I noticed that you use `f"{{:>{customer_defined_len}}}"`. I tried before using `f"{:>{customer_defined_len}}"` which doesn't work. Can you tell me more why your method?

Comment: Wow, this deserves an upvote. Can't believe I was missing the extra braces around the expression....

Comment: @drbombe your attempt didn't work because the `f-string` was attempting to interpret the ^outer^ `{}`. What you want is for it to leave the outer braces as is (to be interpreted by the following `.format()s`) and instead, just interpret the ^inner^ `{}`. iow, you want to [escape the braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5466478/262108).